# ErrorException for installing php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

Tags: laravel, angular-ui-bootstrap, laravel-artisan

ErrorException
copy(C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\js/bootstrap.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

at C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:70
66▕      * @return void
67▕      */
68▕     protected static function updateBootstrapping()
69▕     {
➜  70▕         copy(**DIR**.'/bootstrap-stubs/bootstrap.js', resource_path('js/bootstrap.js'));
71▕     }
72▕ }
73▕

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:70
copy()

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:19
Laravel\Ui\Presets\Bootstrap::updateBootstrapping()

Comment: i installed composer and update it and laravel trough it